InvalidOperationException was unhandled - C#
I'm coding a button to insert data into a table in a SQL Server database. When I debug, I get this error:

InvalidOperationException was unhandled.

It was highlighting the line
sdadap.Fill(dtab);

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2012.
This is my code for the button click handler:
private void btnAddUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Items(Barcode,Item,Type,Price)" + "VALUES('" + this.txtBarcode.Text + "','" + this.txtItem.Text + "','" + this.cmbType.SelectedItem + "','" + this.txtPrice.Text + "')";

    conn = new SqlConnection(conString);

    SqlCommand runquery = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    SqlDataAdapter sdadap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Barcode FROM Items WHERE Barcode='" + this.txtBarcode.Text + "'", conn);

    DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
    sdadap.Fill(dtab);
        
    if (txtBarcode.Text == "" || txtItem.Text == "" || cmbType.SelectedItem == "" || txtPrice.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error...", "Please complete the missing data.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else;

    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            runquery.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Good added","Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

Thank you!

You should not use string concatenation to create SQL statements, you should use proper parameterized queries. Also, you call the sdadap.Fill(dtab); command but you have not executed the INSERT so the command will most likely fail.

Also, what's with interleaving commands? This code looks weird

What does the rest of the exception show? I'm sure it provides more detail than that.

if u need just add data to table, u can try this:
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (airplane_name.Text != "" && date_oi.Text != "" && capacity.Text != "" && Last_ts.Text != "" && flight_hours.Text != "")
    {
        string sql = $"insert into Airplanes values ('{airplane_name.Text}','{date_oi.Text}',{capacity.Text},'{Last_ts.Text}',{flight_hours.Text})";
        AeroportTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data add");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fail");
    }
}

